# How to to redirect a form to a certain node for anonymous users?

Tags: 8, forms

In a custom module, I have a form that is triggered by an option in a menu.
I'd want this form to be redirected automatically (without action of the user) to a certain node (/node/2) when the user is not authenticated.
In the `public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {`, I know how to not display the fields of the form for the anonymous user:

```
$oCurrentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
if ($oCurrentUser->isAnonymous()) {
} else {

some fields...    

$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
];
return $form;
}
```

I guess that redirection might be done with   `$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);`
but I don't know how to make it work...
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using kiamlaluno's advice, the route for the menu is now associated to /association/showMembership.

```
association.membership_showMembership:
  path: '/association/showMembership'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\association\Controller\MembershipController::showMembership'
    _title: 'Membership'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

The controller class uses the following code.

```
class MembershipController extends ControllerBase {
  public function showMembership() {
    if ($this->currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
      return $this->redirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);
    }
    return $this->formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\association\Form\Membership');
  }
}
```

The `Membership` form doesn't redirect users in `buildForm()`.

Answer (score 2):

The class implementing [`FormInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormInterface.php/interface/FormInterface/8.7.x) is allowed to return an instance of a class extending the [`Response`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Response.php/class/Response/8.7.x) class, despite [`FormInterface::buildForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormInterface.php/function/FormInterface%3A%3AbuildForm/8.7.x) not documenting it. See what a comment in the [`FormBuilder::retrieveForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AretrieveForm/8.7.x) code says.

> Exceptions should not be used for code flow control. However, the Form API currently allows any form builder functions to return a response.
>   @see https://www.drupal.org/node/2363189

This means that code similar to the following one would actually work.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Verify the currently logged in user is an anonymous user and redirect.
  if ($this->currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    return $this->redirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);
  }
}
```

Although, since [Do not allow form builder functions to return Response objects](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363189) (the bug report linked in the comment) is open for Drupal 8.8.x, that code could not work anymore, in future.

See also the following comment in the [`FormBuilder::buildForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AbuildForm/8.7.x) code.

> Exceptions should not be used for code flow control. However, the Form API does not integrate with the HTTP Kernel based architecture of Drupal 8. In order to resolve this issue properly it is necessary to completely separate form submission from rendering.
>   @see https://www.drupal.org/node/2367555

The linked issue is [Deprecate EnforcedResponseException support](https://www.drupal.org/node/2367555) (a task, not a bug report).

A module that works also after the change described in that issue is implemented would:

- Associate a controller to the route, not a form builder
- In the controller method associated with the route, redirect the anonymous users to the node page, or render the form for authenticated users

  ```
  class RedirectOrFormController extends ControllerBase {
    public function showForm() {
      if ($this->currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
        return $this->redirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);
      }

      return $this->formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\\locale\\Form\\TranslateEditForm');
    }
  }
  ```

Replace `'Drupal\\locale\\Form\\TranslateEditForm'` with the fully qualified name of the form builder.

Comment: That was my thought precisely, but I wonder how can we do that for ContentEntity forms

Answer (score 1):

In buildForm() you can return a redirect response the same way as in a controller:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($this->currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
      return $this->redirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);
    }

    // build $form for authenticated users

    return $form;
  }
```

Use `$form_state->setRedirect()` if you want to redirect in a form submit handler.

---

Using `buildForm()` as controller by specifying `_form` instead of `_controller` is documented and widely used (not in FormInterface, but on DO: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system). It's unlikely core will ask devs to replace it by their own controller.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right. you can redirect to the node using the code that you have mentioned. There is another way to set the redirection check the below code.

use the name space :

```
 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
$response = new RedirectResponse(node url);
$response->send();
exit(0);
```

I don't know what you are trying to achieve hope this code may help you.

Comment: exits should not be needed

Comment: @Kevin is correct: `exit()` should not be used.

Comment: This is also not how redirects are done in a form builder.